# Loading a WebView with a specific offset

Tags: webview

i'm building an Application that should load an html rendered webpage, it works but, as should be, it loads the view from the top of the page, what if i want it to load from a specific offset ? i've tryed to add the parameters ScrollX and ScrollY in the layout, but it just made the app crash... so how can i achieve such a behavior?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `contentOffset` of your `WEbView`-
 And the code will be like this -

```
[webView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,-20) animated:YES];
```